# Hill valley problem statement does not pass all test cases

Tags: python, for-loop

A list of numbers is said to be a hill if it consists of an ascending sequence followed by a descending sequence, where each of the sequences is of length at least two. Similarly, a list of numbers is said to be a valley if it consists of an descending sequence followed by an ascending sequence. You can assume that consecutive numbers in the input sequence are always different from each other.

Write a Python function hillvalley(l) that takes a list l of integers and returns True if it is a hill or a valley, and False otherwise.

Here are some examples to show how your function should work.

```
hillvalley([1,2,3,5,4])
True
```

```
hillvalley([1,2,3,4,5])
False
```

```
hillvalley([5,4,1,2,3])
True
```

```
hillvalley([5,4,3,2,1])
False
```

```
def hillvalley(l):
  if len(l)<2:
    return False
  
  is_hill = False
  is_valley = False
  
  for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
    if l[i]<l[i+1]:
      if l[i+1]==len(l)-1:
        is_hill = False
        break
    elif l[i]>l[i+1]:
      for j in range(i,len(l)-1):
        if l[j]>l[j+1]:
          if l[j+1]==len(l)-1:
            is_hill = True
            break
        elif l[j]<l[j+1]:
          is_hill = False
          
  for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
    if l[i]>l[i+1]:
      if l[i+1]==len(l)-1:
        is_valley = False
        break
    elif l[i]<l[i+1]:
      for j in range(i,len(l)-1):
        if l[j]<l[j+1]:
          if l[j+1]==len(l)-1:
            is_valley = True
            break
        elif l[j]>l[j+1]:
          is_valley = False
          
  if l[0]>l[1]:
    is_hill = False
  else:
    is_valley = False
          
  return is_hill or is_valley
```

Test Case 8

```
hillvalley([1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1])
True
False\n
Wrong Answer
```

Test Case 9

```
hillvalley([1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,5,3,2,1])
False
False\n
Passed after ignoring Presentation Error
```

Test Case 10

```
hillvalley([9,5,4,-1,-2,3,7])
True
False\n
Wrong Answer
```

Test Case 11

```
hillvalley([5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3])
False
False\n
Passed after ignoring Presentation Error
```

Expecting that my code would pass all testcases but it is giving exact opposite outputs for 2 test cases.

Comment: Please explain what should happen when two subsequent values are equal. We can imagine several test cases for that, like `[1, 1, 2, 1]` `[1, 2, 2, 1]` `[1, 2, 2, 3, 2]`, `[2, 2, 1, 2]`, `[2, 1, 1, 2]` `[1, 2, 1, 1]` ...etc. What is the expected result for such?

Comment: What you really want to do is construct a finite state machine. I bet there are a bunch of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

At two places you have a comparison of *data* with a *length*, which makes no sense:

```
 if l[j+1]==len(l)-1:
```

This should be

```
 if j+1==len(l)-1:
```

If two subsequent values are not allowed to be equal, then you need to check for that too. You can immediately `return False` if anywhere you find that two neighboring values are equal.

I would suggest to avoid repetition of code, and treat hill/valley with the same code. You could use a boolean variable to indicate whether you are currently on a climb, or on a descent. Another boolean could become true when you find a peek, i.e. when the climb becomes a descent or vice versa. If this happens a second time, we have two extremes and should quit.

Here is how that would look:

```
def hillvalley(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return False
    found_peak = False
    ascending = lst[0] < lst[1]
    for prev, nxt in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        if prev == nxt:
            return False
        if (prev < nxt) != ascending:  # change in direction
            ascending = not ascending
            if found_peak:  # two peeks found
                return False
            found_peak = True
    return found_peak
```

Again, this assumes that if ever two neighboring values are equal, the function should return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that successive values are not equal. So it will be a hill or valley … if and only if there is a single change in sign of the slope; i.e. if the number of times that

`(L[i+1] - L[i]) * (L[i] - L[i-1]) < 0`

is precisely 1.